# Control flash with javascript when different domains?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, cross-domain

I have a website on my server which loads a .swf file and then I want to be able and call functions in that file from javascript.

My server has domain **www.A.com** and I load the flash file from domain **www.B.com**:

```
<object id="mp3player" data="http://www.B.com/mp3player.swf" />
```

Then I try to call a function in the flash file with Javascript:

```
mp3player.playSound("http://www.C.com/song.mp3");
```

That doesn't work. On the *Javascript console* I get

> mp3player.playSound is not a function

This works perfectly if I call the flash file from **www.A.com** instead of **www.B.com** without errors.
On my mp3player.swf I have already added the line

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
```

This drives me crazy! Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Have you added a [`cross-domain policy`](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) to all domains?

Comment: I don't see the reason for that. I want to call functions in the flash from javascript, not the vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess would be that the connection to server B is slower than what it is to server A, so A is faster than B which in result gives a javascript trying to load a file that the computer haven't recieved yet. (Did I use haven't correct there? Or should it be hasn't? Bleh)

Comment: I think hasn't is correct though it's more a debate for this site http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasn%27t+versus+haven%27t according to dictionary.com, has - a 3rd person singular present indicative of have.  So something else, the computer (3rd person, singular), present in that the verb tense is present, and indicative, in that it is implied fact that this is what is occurring. http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/indicmoodterm.htm If only I'd paid attention in English I wouldn't have had to look that all up.  But I disagree with your answer, I may be wrong but I think Marty is right.

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly set allowScriptAccess in the HTML page? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ea6.html

Comment: allowScriptAccess is just for communication from the flash to the page. What I want is the opposite